# listing all functions in a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to list all the functions in one module but i'm stuck on an point.
i just get only the functions in `__init__.py`
 but not all the functions in the package. this is the code what i al ready have made:

```
import package
functions = []
for i in dir(package):
    functions.append(i)
print(functions)
```

so now i get a list of all functions in `__init__.py` but not over the whole package. how to get all the functions in 'package'?
i want to get it like this:

```
import package
functions = []
for i in dir(package):
    #here like adding function and then make package function.other_package
print(functions)
```

can someone help me plz?

> it is not a duplicate becuse i not want a doc but just only all the functions of all the files in a package

Comment: If you say `pacakge`, do you just mean all files under a specific folder that you want to be the package root, or do you have a number of `import` statements that define what the package is?

Comment: What is `package`? Where is it defined?

Comment: i mean like tqdm package is tqdm and yes it is imported

Answer (score 2):

The definition of what a `package` exactly is is a little tricky, so I'll only assume the very basics: You have a directory that you assume to be the package root, and a number of python files directly in it or nested deeper that you assume to be part of the package. Something like this maybe:

```
# package foo
foo
├── bar.py               # has a function "bar"
├── __init__.py          # has a function "foo" 
└── baz
    ├── qux.py           # has functions "baz" and "qux"
    └── __init__.py
```

And you expect something like this as the result:

```
foo/bar.py: [bar]
foo/__init__.py: [foo]
foo/baz/qux.py: [qux, baz]
foo/baz/__init__.py: []
```

If *no other assumption* is made, the only way to learn what functions your package contains is to ask python itself to compile the files and show their content:

```
import os
import inspect
import typing

# find all python files below a certain folder
files = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk('path/to/a/package/foo'):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            files.append(os.sep.join([dirpath, filename]))

for f in files:
    # turn the files into code objects and find declared constants
    functions = []
    code_obj = compile(open(f).read(), f, 'exec')
    members = dict(inspect.getmembers(code_obj))
    for idx in range(len(members['co_consts'])//2):
        val = members['co_consts'][idx * 2]
        name = members['co_consts'][idx * 2 + 1]
        # suboptimal: this check also allows lambdas and classes 
        if isinstance(val, types.CodeType):
            functions.append(name)
    print(f'{f}: {functions}')
```

This snipped prints exactly the above result for me. As far as I know, there is no way to ask a package about **all** its functions, and not only those it willingly exposes.

---

See also [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611619/is-it-possible-to-access-inner-functions-and-classes-via-code-objects) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162664/how-to-execute-nested-pycode-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) for alternative and more accurate (albeit more complicated) ways to extract functions from code objects.