# How to execute nested PyCode objects

Tags: python

Let's say we have a code object like this:

```
code = '''
x = 'unrelated'
y = dangerous_function()

def foo():
    return 'say foo'
'''
code_obj = compile(code, '<string>', 'exec')
```

I don't want to just execute it, because who knows what will happen (the `dangerous_function` call in particular looks shifty). But I *would* like to populate my current scope with any functions that are defined in there, which looks to be possible by doing this:

```
import types    

new_objects = []
for obj in code_obj.co_consts:
    if isinstance(obj, types.CodeType):
        new_objects.append(obj.co_name)
        print(obj)           # "<code object foo at 0x7f4e255d3150, file "<string>", line 4>"
                             # ... looks promising, so let's exec it!
        exec(obj)

print(new_objects[0])        # "foo"
print(eval(new_objects[0]))  # "NameError: name 'foo' is not defined"
```

I would have expected the last statement to print `say foo` instead of raising a `NameError`. The reason for that must be that `exec(obj)` doesn't do what I expected it to do, i.e. it doesn't run the code object that was assigned to the name `foo` within the parent code object.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `co_const` attribute holds just the constant literals defined in a code object, so in your example it holds just the code that loads `'say foo'` as an argument for return, which can be verified with `dis`:

```
import dis
for obj in code_obj.co_consts:
    if isinstance(obj, types.CodeType):
        dis.dis(obj)
```

This outputs:

```
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('say foo')
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

So by executing this code object it naturally would not define any names.

If you would like to execute just a specific function in a given source code, you can parse the code with `ast.parse` and use a `ast.NodeVisitor` subclass to extract the function node, wrap it with a `Module` node so you can compile and execute it alone:

```
import ast

class get_function(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.code = None

    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        if node.name == self.name:
            self.code = compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.Module(body=[node])), '<string>', 'exec')

func = get_function('foo')
func.visit(ast.parse(code, '<string>'))
exec(func.code)
print(eval('foo'))
```

This outputs:

```
<function foo at 0x018735D0>
```

EDIT: Alternatively and more simply, you can use the `ast.walk` function to traverse the nodes with a `for` loop:

```
import ast

for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code, '<string>')):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) and node.name == 'foo':
        code_obj = compile(ast.fix_missing_locations(ast.Module(body=[node])), '<string>', 'exec')

exec(code_obj)
print(eval('foo'))
```

Comment: I see what your goal is now. I've updated my answer accordingly then.